# HTML Dropdown box shifting html elements downwards

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, z-index, dropdown

So I'm trying to make a dropdown list overlap the elements below when expanded. Unfortunately, even when elements in the same stacking context have a position, and dropdown container div set to a z-index of 2, the issue still persists; instead of overlapping the elements below, it shifts them down. I have also attempted shuffling around the stacking context by adding the opacity property to various elements, but that hasn't worked either. The code can be seen below:

```css
#firstone {
  z-index: 2;
}

#contain {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 25, 25, 0.2);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.fancy_input_box {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 3% 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.fancy_input {
  font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #aaa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 7px 7px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

.fancy_input:focus~.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  cursor: default;
}

.fancy_input:focus~.dropdown-content>span {
  display: block;
  cursor: default;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 222px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content:active {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content>span {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content>span:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.fancy_input~.fancy_label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 10px;
  color: #aaa;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.fancy_input:focus~.fancy_label {
  top: -18px;
  left: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grey !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}

.fancy_input:focus {
  border: 1px solid grey !important;
}

.fancy_input:not(focus):valid~.fancy_label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 1px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="contain">

    <div id="firstone" class="fancy_input_box">
      <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="25" size="25" required>
      <label class="fancy_label">Search</label>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <span>a</span>
        <span>b</span>
        <span>c</span>
        <span>d</span>
        <span>e</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fancy_input_box">
      <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
      <label class="fancy_label">Thing</label>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <div class="fancy_input_box">
        <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
        <label class="fancy_label">stuff</label>
      </div>

      <div class="fancy_input_box">
        <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
        <label class="fancy_label">more stuff</label>
      </div>

      <div class="fancy_input_box">
        <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
        <label class="fancy_label">more stuff</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add `z-index` to `.dropdown-content` and change `position` property to `absolute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dropdown content should be absolute positioned.

Update your dropdown styles as shown below :

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 222px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try following code just set position absolute. also i change width 100% in dropdown-content div for good design.**

```css
#firstone {
  z-index: 2;
}

#contain {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 25, 25, 0.2);
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.fancy_input_box {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 3% 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.fancy_input {
  font: 15px/24px "Lato", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #aaa;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 7px 7px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
}

.fancy_input:focus~.dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  cursor: default;
}

.fancy_input:focus~.dropdown-content>span {
  display: block;
  cursor: default;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  
}

.dropdown-content:active {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content>span {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-content>span:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.fancy_input~.fancy_label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 10px;
  color: #aaa;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.fancy_input:focus~.fancy_label {
  top: -18px;
  left: 1px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: grey !important;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}

.fancy_input:focus {
  border: 1px solid grey !important;
}

.fancy_input:not(focus):valid~.fancy_label {
  top: -18px;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 1px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">

    <div id="firstone" class="fancy_input_box">
      <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="25" size="25" required>
      <label class="fancy_label">Search</label>

      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <span>a</span>
        <span>b</span>
        <span>c</span>
        <span>d</span>
        <span>e</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fancy_input_box">
      <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
      <label class="fancy_label">Thing</label>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div>
      <div class="fancy_input_box">
        <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
        <label class="fancy_label">stuff</label>
      </div>

      <div class="fancy_input_box">
        <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
        <label class="fancy_label">more stuff</label>
      </div>

      <div class="fancy_input_box">
        <input class="fancy_input" type="text" placeholder="" maxlength="4" size="10">
        <label class="fancy_label">more stuff</label>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add **position:absoute** and **top:100%;** in your dropdown-content class

[jsfiddle from your code](http://jsfiddle.net/78a306gy/)

```
  .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 222px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: @robert check this sol. I've attached jsfiddle